# Is there any way to send form input (pdfs) as attachments with wp_mail?

Tags: php, wordpress, pdf

I'm building a site for an HR Agency. For every job ad they have on their site, the candidate needs to be able to apply through a form.
The form gets content like name, wage as string and int. But it is also important to upload a pdf.
The content and pdf is supposed to be send via wp_mail() to the agency.
Everything works perfectly except the PDF.
I have been searching for a solution for about 2 weeks, but I am still stuck.

Help would be more than awesome to receive :)

To fix the problem I already tried several Wordpress Methods to upload the pdf to my Wordpress uploads and my plan was afterwards to send the uploaded pdf via wp_mail().

Functions I already tried:

- wp_upload_bits()
- wp_handle_upload()
- move_uploaded_file()

This is the form without all the inputs which are already working:

```
<form method="POST" action="https://domainname.com/form-sent/">                                                              
 <div class="form-group">                                        
  <label for="files">Bewerbungsunterlagen</label>                                        
  <input type="file" class="form-control-file" name="files" 
  required>                                      
 </div>                                                                          
 <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Jetzt Bewerben! 
 </button>                              
</form>
```

This is the relevant php of the success message page, where the user is directed after he submits the form:

```
$to = "emailOfAgency";
$from = $_POST['email'];
$files = $_FILES['files'];
$headers = "From:" . $from;

wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, $files);
```

The email is perfectly send with wp_mail(), but there is no attachment send with it.

Perfect result would be:
Mail sent with attachments.

Comment: What does the [`wp_mail()` manpage](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/) say about the `$attachments` parameter? Compare/show what your `$files` contains instead.

Comment: Where are your files stored ? check the function with a static file first.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who faces the same problem here is what fixed my code:

In the form input I changed post to lowercase and added enctype="multipart/form-data". In addition to that I added accept="application/pdf" on the type input field.

```
<form method="post" action="https://domainname.com/form-sent/" 
enctype="multipart/form-data">                                                              
  <div class="form-group">                                        
     <label for="files">Bewerbungsunterlagen</label>                                        
     <input type="file" class="form-control-file" name="files" 
     accept="application/pdf" required>                                      
  </div>                                                                          
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Jetzt Bewerben! 
  </button>                              
</form>
```

On the success message page I added wp_handle_upload() to upload the pdf to the uploads and then send it with wp_mail():

```
$to = "emailOfAgency";
$from = $_POST['email'];

// upload files
    if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_handle_upload' ) ) {
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
    }

    $uploadedfile = $_FILES['files'];

    $upload_overrides = array( 'test_form' => false );

    $movefile = wp_handle_upload( $uploadedfile, $upload_overrides );

    if ( $movefile && ! isset( $movefile['error'] ) ) {
        $doesItWork = "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
    } else {
        /**
         * Error generated by _wp_handle_upload()
         * @see _wp_handle_upload() in wp-admin/includes/file.php
         */
        $doesItWork = $movefile['error'];
    }

    // end upload files

$headers = "From:" . $from;

wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, $files);
```

Hope this helps someone in the near future! :)